# configure fail : guacamole

Tags: web, vnc, vnc-server, guacamole

when I configued guacamole, I meet some problems which I can't solve it immediately. when I open the browser to enter URL(ip:8080/guacmole), the error occured:

404 Not Found
The path '/guacamole/' was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 606, in respond

cherrypy.response.body = self.handler()

File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cherrypy/_cperror.py", line 227, in **call**

raise self
NotFound: (404, "The path '/guacamole/' was not found.")

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using CherryPy as webserver for guacamole? Guacamole is written in jsp. CherryPy is a simple low level webserver and it can't deploy .war files like guacamole. You should use a webserver that does support jsp web pages. I recommend using tomcat since the guacamole tutorial is written with the tomcat webserver, but glassfish would work too.